# R3InjectorError(ProductModule)[MatSelect]NullInjectorError:No provider for MatSelect

Tags: angular, angular16

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4ISY.png)

How we can resolve this issue? As of now, we can't use the MDC version of Material 16 so we are using the Material 16 legacy version...Any way we can resolve this?Note it I am using Ngx mat select search version 7 and Material 16 legacy version

1]I am stuck on this issue
2]I tried to downgrade the ngx mat select search version to 6...but the ngx mat select  search UI is disturbed.

Comment: where are you importing MatSelectModule?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of linking to an image of an error, it is considered better to place the error text directly in your code. You can also format it as code using the provided tools.

Comment: in Material module file which is custom file i imported in app module